# hovering text does not show up properly in PHP?

Tags: php, html, hover

i want to display a text formatted in a div that shows up when hovering over a text. I managed this this way in my PHP-file:

```
echo "<style> " . ".'runes" . $i . ":hover'" . "{" . 
     "position: absolute;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
      width: 225px;
      height: 300px;
      margin-left: -20px;
      margin-top: -267px;
      text-align: center;
      border: 1px solid #fff;
      -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
      -moz-border-radius: 5px;
      border-radius: 25px;}" . "</style>";
echo "<div class='runes" . $i . ":hover'" . "><div class='runestext'>TEXT</div></div>";
```

And in my CSS-file:

```
.runestext {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

My problem is, that the div with `class=runes` shows up properly, but the text i want to display in this div formatted with `class=runestext` shows up unformatted in the middle of the page. Where is the mistake?
Thanks.

PS: Do not worry about the `$i`, that is because i loop the whole code 10 times for getting 10div's.

Comment: The PHP is irrelevant to your question. Post the rendered HTML and CSS please.

Comment: You don't have a closing curly brace in your style tag.

Comment: In your echo statement, you're not encapsulating your class names.

It should be something like echo "<div class='runes'>

Comment: @McCormick32 edited my code, does not change anything.. same with encapsulating